# ¿Consultas SQL e informes en ACCESS?

Tags: sql, ms-access, informes

explico un poco mi problema y la solución que he venido dando, y donde estoy atascado.

### Introducción

Estoy desarrollando un modulo de informes en Access, que se alimenta de dos bd, una de PostgreSQL y la otra de MySQL.

### 1.Generar informe partiendo de dos variables que ingresa el usuario:

**tipo_documento** y **numero_factura**

cuando el usuario ingresa el **tipo_factura** y **numero_factura**.

esta me trae todo los datos asociados a esa factura:

> ***fecha_factura***:
>
> ***tipo_factura***:
>
> ***numero_factura***:
>
> ***nombre_cliente***
>
> ***lote_pk***
>
> ***cod_producto***
>
> ***tipo_producto***
>
> ***ref***
>
> ***tllnombre***

ejemplo:

**tipo_documento:PKE**

**numero_factura: 7**

resultado:

[image: factura]

luego debo consultar en la tabla **conversionref** si algún

> ***cod_producto***

existe en la columna **conversion**

esta es mi tabla **conversionref**

[image: conversionref]

si encuentra algún código **converison** que coincida entonces debe tomar el código del la columna **referencia**.

ejemplo:

del los resultados anterior el código 8317 coincide en la columna **conversion**, entonces debe coger el código **referencia**=8314 y el **lote_pk**=205001 y consultar en otra consulta que se llama **datosgenerales**

esto me traerá una cierta cantidad de datos, pero solo mostrare los relevantes ej:

[image: datosgenerales]

estos datos son del código **referencia**=8314 pero deben quedar con el código **8317** de la factura, aparte de eso en la factura anterior traigo un campo que se llama *ref* con ese campo, nos damos cuenta a que tipo pertenece ese código.

ese **codigo** 8317 de la factura es **ref**=8 es decir "CONGELADO MARINADO".

entonces debe ejecutarme el informe para los de tipo=8,
con los datos del 8314, solo que el código que sale en ese informe debe ser 8317.

y resto de códigos de la factura que no están en la tabla **conversionref** se consultan directamente en la tabla **datosgenerales** aparte de eso también debe ejecutarse en los otros informes según su tipo **ref**.

Lo estaba manejando buscando los códigos de la factura directamente en la tabla **datosgenerales** pero cuando nos enteramos que no estaban saliendo algunos informes era porque no estaba encontrando los códigos que son de tipo **conversion** que son los que están en esa tabla conversión que tienen los mismo datos de el código **referencia**, dependiendo del tipo **ref** hay algunos datos que no toma.

El caso es que estoy un poco perdido en implementar eso para los códigos de tipo conversión.

**nota:** los otros informes son los que se deben ejecutar según el tipo **ref** de el código de la factura.

y se llenan con los datos devueltos de la tabla **datosgenerales**

Comment: Uff q largo, pq no vas directamente a lo que necesitas, cuando uno ve una pregunta tan larga se le hace muy difícil la lectura, se claro y breve por favor

Comment: @Japv modifique la consulta, espero hacerme entender, no sé como explicarlo de una mejor manera, y ya llevo rato  intentando integrar a una solución.

Comment: Por favor, modificá el título de tu pregunta, así por lo menos se tiene una pista breve de lo que estás buscando. Leé [ask], en especial la sección _Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico_.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas relacionar tus dos tablas: facturas y conversiónref ¿Sabes relacionar tablas o tienes nociones de cómo hacerlo? Por lo que veo en el ejemplo, necesitas una relación uno a uno entre las dos tablas/consultas. De esta manera manera, la consulta resultante mostrará ambas tablas relacionadas y únicamente tendrás que filtrar con criterio tipo_documento y numero de factura para obtener el resultado en una consulta. Dichos criterios de filtrado los podrás introducir desde un formulario, pero para esto debes de dominar la creación de formularios y los elementos que puede contener, dado que los valores tendrás que vincularlos a la consulta. En resumen, dinos qué conocimientos de Access tienes y ver qué se puede apañar.

Comment: Saludos, de he hecho ya tengo el formulario creado, el cual me pide al  usuario **tipo_documento** y **numero_factura*** estos son los que me trae todos los códigos productos, lotes de esos productos y a que tipo pertenecen(son 4 tipos), es decir que también tengo 4 informes por cada tipo.  y una consulta general para todos los códigos y lote que trae esa factura, el problema que estoy teniendo es con los códigos de tipo conversión que trae la factura. ya que las uniones de los códigos de la factura las tengo directamente en las consultas por tipo de código.